# No WiFi option in Ubuntu 16 in HP probook 450 G3

Tags: networking, drivers, 16.04, hp, iwlwifi

I have recently installed ubuntu 16.04 LTS on my new HP probook 450 G3, by dual boot. The wifi menu does not show any option to connect to wifi, I am using usb tethering. I ran this command from another question - [Wi-Fi on hp probook 450 G2](https://askubuntu.com/questions/662090/wi-fi-on-hp-probook-450-g2)

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:hanipouspilot/rtlwifi
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install rtlwifi-new-dkms linux-firmware
```

And selected yes to wherever it asked in the command terminal. But no result.

I have also downloaded [this file](http://h20564.www2.hp.com/hpsc/swd/public/detail?sp4ts.oid=5359406&swItemId=ob_122899_1&swEnvOid=2020) but it is a `tar` file and I don't know how to install. Plus I am not sure if it will work.

Thanks for answers!

Comment: Tar files usually have an script called ./config, to install em. Descompress the file and read the readme, it usually says where is the script or instructions of how to install the package

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` terminal command.

Answer (score 0):

1. input the command below in the terminal to check whether is because the network manager is closed.

   > sudo /etc/init.d/network-manager start

If this doesn't work,

2. when booting the computer, enter BIOS, close the secure boot. Then, install your wireless card driver. 
   As for how to install, you can see [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers?newreg=c0cb10f97b83453c91682f3e409c5e21)

Hope it can help you.

Answer (score 0):

I also ran into same problem. I have same HP probook 450-G3. 
Solution is to connect to Internet with Ethernet. Open Additional Drivers(comes Pre-installed) from dashboard, check for available drivers and Apply. This should install Wifi drivers compatible with your hardware.

Also while installing ubuntu (for next time) , you should check on installing third-party softwares, that will automatically install wifi drivers as well.

[image: see the pic]